# crashing app on press button ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please help me, i don`t understand how i can resolve this problem, i have successfull build but when i press button my application crashed, but i checked this button declare in .h file

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AddAddressVC 0x7fe14984cc00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key house.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059531e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104fe8031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001059530b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000104a09b47 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107135ec0 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107423e8a -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058f5e8d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107422834 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010713d0d7 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010713da04 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010713dd21 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010713e574 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010716fc0e -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 945
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107186582 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010718786c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001073dfd0b -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001070697a8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106bf9456 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106bfd667 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106b840fb _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106bb179c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106f942ef _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 167
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001078f9662 __handleEventQueueInternal + 6875
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058f5bb1 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058da4af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058d9a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001058d930b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010c8eca73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000106f9a057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    29  Grocery Store                       0x00000001040bbb5f main + 111
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109326955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Your storyboard has a connection to an outlet `house` that doesn't exist in your `AddressVC`

Comment: search "house" name outlet in your storyboard.

Comment: thanks guys i understood how read error in terminal